# Which version of Python is preferable for Windows 7 (32-Bit)?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently using Python version 3.3.0.

But it shows me syntax error in `else`, `elif` though I did everything correct.

Comment: Compare your code with the example at http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html  Tell us if something differs (e.g. a missing `:` as suggested by @paxdiablo)

Comment: tamal, without showing us the code, this question will be of dubious quality for future visitors. That means there's a real risk it will be closed and/or deleted. Please keep that in mind when you come back.

Answer (score 2):

If it's giving you a syntax error then I would suggest you *haven't* done everything correctly. That's my answer by the way, the rest below is just extra help.

It's incredibly unlikely you found a bug in Python's `if` statement when it's been tested by millions of people on the planet, millions of times a day. Far more likely is that there's a problem in *your* use of it, which has been tested by, well, just you :-)

Post your code, that's the only way to be sure. It's possible that you're relying on Python2 code in your Python3 environment but I don't think the `if` construct changed so it's doubtful.

It's possible your indentation is incorrect. It's possible you may be missing a `:`.

There are a hundred things you could be doing wrong but, unfortunately, we can't tell without the code.

By the way, the best version of Python to use is the latest stable release for your OS of choice, in either the Python2 or Python3 stream (depending on whether you need the older one). That's (at the time of this answer) `2.7.4` and `3.3.1`.